# Is it mandatory to insert a new record just before calling lastInsertId() to get the last inserted ID in PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, last-insert-id, insert-query

I'm trying to learn PDO.

First, I inserted a record in a table successfully using below code.

```
<?php
  $servername = "localhost";
  $username = "root";
  $password = "";
  $dbname = "myDBPDO";

  try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email)
    VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')";
    // use exec() because no results are returned
    $conn->exec($sql);
    echo "New record created successfully";
  }
  catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
  }

  $conn = null;
?>
```

Then, I tried to get the ID of last inserted record. I wrote following code for it :

```
<?php
  $servername = "localhost";
  $username = "root";
  $password = "";
  $dbname = "myDBPDO";

  try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $last_id = $conn->lastInsertId();
    echo "Last inserted ID is: " . $last_id;
  }
  catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
  }

  $conn = null;
?>
```

Output of above(second code snippet) is as follows :

```
Last inserted ID is: 0
```

Actually, I expected to get the below output :

```
Last inserted ID is: 1
```

**1** is the value in ID field of the record I inserted in first program.

Why it's not returning the expected output as specified above?

**Is it mandatory to insert a new record just before calling lastInsertId() to get the last inserted ID in PDO?**

If yes, then how should I get the last inserted id without inserting a new record just before calling lastInsertId() using the second code snippet I've written? If no, what's the reason for it?

Comment: I am confused as to why you would not just get lastInsertId right after you make your INSERT... Why are you doing it separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying database call [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) operates per-connection. If you sever the connection, the value is lost

> The ID that was generated is maintained in the server on a **per-connection basis**. This means that the value returned by the function to a given client is the first `AUTO_INCREMENT` value generated for most recent statement affecting an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column **by that client**

So to answer your question...

> Is it mandatory to insert a new record just before calling lastInsertId() to get the last inserted ID in PDO?

Yes, that is correct.

---

> how should I get the last inserted id without inserting a new record

You're pretty much limited to fetching the maximum ID value

```
$maxId = $conn->query('SELECT MAX(id) FROM MyGuests')->fetchColumn();
```

Alternately, save the `lastInsertId()` value from the first script somewhere that can be retrieved by the second script.